# Display bug in beta sites chat

Tags: bug, tags, chat

I've noticed that sometimes, when messages with [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) in them get starred, the display of them in the star list gets buggy and weird.

> Take some time to visit [this meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/do-we-want-to-have-automatic-tag-deletion) to help us decide if we should keep the tag pruning script active in our community. Our 6 month anniversary is coming up (gratz everyone!), whichs means one-time used tags will be pruned and left [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged). Any comments, suggestions, or proposals are welcome.

is shown like so:
[image]

You can see it in the **[Anime & Manga SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga)**.